How to choose between footnotes and endnotes for each part in an AMS book class document?
I am using the amsbook class for my LaTeX document and need the flexibility to choose whether notes should appear as footnotes at the bottom of the page or as endnotes at the end of each part. Additionally, I want each note number to be clickable, allowing readers to easily navigate to the corresponding note text.
Here's an example of what I've tried so far:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote=\endnote

\begin{document}

\part{First Part}

\chapter{First Chapter}
Here is some text with a note\footnote{Here is a note in the first chapter.}.

\chapter{Second Chapter}
Here is some more text with another note\footnote{Here is another note in the second chapter.}.

\theendnotes

\part{Second Part}

\chapter{Third Chapter}
Here is some text with a note\footnote{Here is a note in the third chapter.}.

\chapter{Fourth Chapter}
Here is some more text with another note\footnote{Here is another note in the fourth chapter.}.

\theendnotes

\end{document}

However, this approach forces all notes to be either footnotes or endnotes. I want to have the option to set notes as footnotes for some parts and as endnotes for others within the same document.
How can I achieve this flexibility in an amsbook class document? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a partial solution to my question which I arrived at using the enotez package. For my taste, it lacks a breakdown of the notes at the end of the parts according to the Chapter in which they appear. I would also have liked clicking on the footnote number to be redirected to its location in the document text.
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{enotez}

% Enotez configuration

\setenotez{
  list-name={Notes},
  backref=true,
  reset=true,
}

% Commands for end-of-part notes

\newcommand{\finishpartnotes}{%
  \printendnotes
}

% Environment for end-of-part notes

\newenvironment{partendnotes}{%

  \let\origfootnote\footnote
  \renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\endnote{##1}}%
}{%

  \let\footnote\origfootnote
  \finishpartnotes
}

% Environment for hyperlinked footnotes

\newcounter{customHfootnote}
\newenvironment{partfootnotes}{%
  \let\origfootnote\footnote
  \renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{customHfootnote}%
    \origfootnote{\hyperref[customHfootnote-\thecustomHfootnote]{##1}}%
    \label{customHfootnote-\thecustomHfootnote}%
  }%
}{%
  \let\footnote\origfootnote
}

\begin{document}

% Part I with endnotes
\begin{partendnotes}
\addpart{First Part}

This is a note before any chapter\footnote{Note hors chapitres avant le premier chapitre de la première partie.}

\chapter{First Chapter}
Here is some text with a note\footnote{Here is the first note in the first chapter.}
Here is more text with another note\footnote{Here is the second note in the first chapter.}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
Here is some more text with a note\footnote{Here is the first note in the second chapter.}
And another note here\footnote{Here is the second note in the second chapter.}

\end{partendnotes}

% Second part with footnotes
\begin{partfootnotes}
\addpart{Second Part}

This is a note before any chapter in the second part\footnote{Note hors chapitres avant le premier chapitre de la deuxième partie.}

\chapter{Third Chapter}
Here is some text with a note\footnote{Here is the first note in the third chapter.}
More text with another note\footnote{Here is the second note in the third chapter.}

\chapter{Fourth Chapter}
Here is some more text with a note\footnote{Here is the first note in the fourth chapter.}
And another note here\footnote{Here is the second note in the fourth chapter.}

\end{partfootnotes}

% Part three with endnote
\begin{partendnotes}
\addpart{Third Part}

This is a note before any chapter in the third part\footnote{Note hors chapitres avant le premier chapitre de la troisième partie.}

\chapter{Fifth Chapter}
Here is some text with a note\footnote{Here is the first note in the fifth chapter.}
More text with another note\footnote{Here is the second note in the fifth chapter.}

\chapter{Sixth Chapter}
Here is some more text with a note\footnote{Here is the first note in the sixth chapter.}
And another note here\footnote{Here is the second note in the sixth chapter.}

\end{partendnotes}

% Part four with footnotes
\begin{partfootnotes}
\addpart{Fourth Part}

This is a note before any chapter in the fourth part\footnote{Note hors chapitres avant le premier chapitre de la quatrième partie.}

\chapter{Seventh Chapter}
Here is some text with a note\footnote{Here is the first note in the seventh chapter.}
More text with another note\footnote{Here is the second note in the seventh chapter.}

\chapter{Eighth Chapter}
Here is some more text with a note\footnote{Here is the first note in the eighth chapter.}
And another note here\footnote{Here is the second note in the eighth chapter.}

\end{partfootnotes}

% Part five with endnotes
\begin{partendnotes}
\addpart{Fifth Part}

This is a note before any chapter in the fifth part\footnote{Note hors chapitres avant le premier chapitre de la cinquième partie.}

\chapter{Ninth Chapter}
Here is some text with a note\footnote{Here is the first note in the ninth chapter.}
More text with another note\footnote{Here is the second note in the ninth chapter.}

\chapter{Tenth Chapter}
Here is some more text with a note\footnote{Here is the first note in the tenth chapter.}
And another note here\footnote{Here is the second note in the tenth chapter.}

\end{partendnotes}

% Part Six with footnotes
\begin{partfootnotes}
\addpart{Sixth Part}

This is a note before any chapter in the sixth part\footnote{Note hors chapitres avant le premier chapitre de la sixième partie.}

\chapter{Eleventh Chapter}
Here is some text with a note\footnote{Here is the first note in the eleventh chapter.}
More text with another note\footnote{Here is the second note in the eleventh chapter.}

\chapter{Twelfth Chapter}
Here is some more text with a note\footnote{Here is the first note in the twelfth chapter.}
And another note here\footnote{Here is the second note in the twelfth chapter.}

\end{partfootnotes}

\end{document}


your example errors for me. Did you actually tried it?

Yes, in fact I tried even too many things with dometimes difficult to understand errors. I have replaced the exemple in my question with a minimal code which compile without error and produces Pdf with notes at the end of each of its two parts.

and then why didn't you mentioned that? Or asked first how to resolve this error? Did you hope that nobody test your code and realize that it dies horribly? If you want to mix footnotes and endnotes simply remove the \let\footnote=\endnote and use \endnote if you want an endnote and \footnote  if you want a footnote. Or use a \myfootnote command and redefine it as needed. Regarding the error: ask a new question explicitly about the error.

Yes, there was a copy/paste error. I'm surprised you didn't realise that. Your solution is not a solution because the document is made up of a large number of parts and the choice of footnotes or endnotes must be absolutely flexible depending on the version of the document. What's more, you don't meet the need to be able to move from endnotes to their location in the document. Thank you for your interest.
